# cut() creates NA break category in R

Tags: r

I am processing my data using R and for that purpose, I have to format my database.

```
data <- database %>%
  group_by(cat_a, cat_b) %>% 
  mutate(
    lengths = cut(length, breaks = seq(0, (max(length)+50), by = 50)),
    heights = cut(height, breaks = seq(0, (max(height)+1), by = 1), dig.lab=5)
  )
```

At this point, when I check the values calculated by `cut()`

```
unique(data$heights)
 [1] (0,1]   (1,2]   (2,3]   (3,4]   (4,5]   (5,6]   (6,7]   (7,8]   (8,9]   (9,10]  (10,11] (11,12] (12,13] <NA>   
Levels: (0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,4] (4,5] (5,6] (6,7] (7,8] (8,9] (9,10] (10,11] (11,12] (12,13]
```

To better understand my problem `max(height)` returns `13.3`. But, if you see the `Levels` the last one is `(12,13]`. This makes me believe that it is the reason to have a `<NA>` at the end at the first line of the result `[1]`.

So, I tried to fix this by setting the breaks in `cut()` by +1 (see: `(max(height)+1)`. But, not just that I don't get a new category, I also still have the NA.

Here I have to add, that omitting the NAs is not the solution, since I believe those are the values that didn't end up in a category. Basically values like 13.3.

Therefore, my question is how to fix this? How can I tell `cut()` to create that one extra category? I know that there is something like `include.lower=TRUE`, so I am looking the opposite, how to include the highest? Maybe my observation is wrong, so I am looking forward to every idea

**UPDATE**
As suggested in the comments:
heights = cut(height, breaks = c(-Inf,seq(0, (max(height)+1), by = 1), Inf), dig.lab=5)

Comment: You can append `Inf` or `-Inf` to take care of all the blocks outside the range i.e. `c(-Inf,  seq(0, (max(length)+50), by = 50), Inf)` in breaks

Comment: @akrun I think it was deffinately a step in the wright direction. But now I get `x lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ`

Comment: I didn't see the `labels` argument in your code

Comment: I am not even passing one, the original call from my code looks like this: `frame_size = cut(frame_size, breaks = seq(0, max(frame_size), by = 1), Inf, dig.lab=5)`

Comment: Where is the `c(` in the `breaks` i.e. `breaks = c(seq(0, max(frame_size), by = 1), Inf)`

Comment: `Inf` is your label argument (matched based on position) because you missed the `c()` wrapping the `breaks`.

Comment: `unique(dist$frame_size)
 [1] (0,1]    (1,2]    (2,3]    (3,4]    (4,5]    (5,6]    (6,7]    (7,8]    (8,9]    (9,10]   (10,11]  (11,12]  (12,Inf] <NA>    
Levels: (0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,4] (4,5] (5,6] (6,7] (7,8] (8,9] (9,10] (10,11] (11,12] (12,Inf]`

Comment: Ugh.... The NA is still present

Comment: @CroatiaHR You may need `-Inf` as well i.e. `breaks = c(-Inf, seq(0, max(frame_size), by = 1), Inf)`

Comment: Can you share the value of `height` (or `frame_size`)? It might make things clearer.

Comment: `-Inf` solved the problem. Thanks for saving me guys. Especially, @akrun it is not the first time you provide me with help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add `-Inf`, `Inf` in `breaks` to remove the `NA`

```
cut(..., breaks = c(-Inf, seq(0, max(frame_size), by = 1), Inf))
```

Answer (score 1):

In such cases you can use `findInterval` which manages such cases automatically without specifying breaks explicitly.

For example,

```
cut(1:10, c(3, 7, 9), labels = FALSE)
# [1] NA NA NA  1  1  1  1  2  2 NA

findInterval(1:10, c(3, 7, 9))
#[1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

So for your case you can use :

```
library(dplyr)

database %>%
  group_by(cat_a, cat_b) %>% 
  mutate(lengths = findInterval(length, seq(0, (max(length)+50), by = 50)))
```

Comment: Very nice solution. I wasn't aware that this function exists.